# Issue related to firing CheckedChange Event of Checkbox inside the Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net application, i have added Repeater in user Control, and inside the repeater i have added `asp Checkbox`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
    onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" 
    onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>    
                     <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSelect" AutoPostBack="true" Visible="false" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" />
                </td>
```

and in CodeBehind file:

```
 protected void chkSelect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = "";
        }
```

But the event doesn't fire when clicking on checkbox.

i have also tried to add dynamically event when itemDataBound event fires of Repeater control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
    onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" 
    onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>    
                     <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSelect" AutoPostBack="true" Visible="false" />
                </td>
```

in Code Behind :

```
   protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row["DataType"].ToString().Trim().Equals("bool"))
            {
                CheckBox chkSelect = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chkSelect");
                chkSelect.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkSelect_CheckedChanged);
                chkSelect.Visible = true;
            }
```

but still event doesn't fire..

how to Invoke an event of CheckBox control that is inside of Repeater Control...

Comment: Is the Repeater1_ItemCommand event handler firing when you click on it?  Also inspect the markup, it should have a reference to __doPostBack somewhere.

Comment: No.. Repeater1_ItemCommand  doesn't fire..

Comment: yes it does have javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$E2wAttributeFiletering$Repeater1$ctl04$chkSelect\',\'\')', 0)

Comment: what to do in these scenarios ??

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get the event to fire if you hooked it up in the `ItemCreated` event rather than the `ItemDataBound` event:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
   {
       CheckBox chkSelect = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chkSelect");
       if(chkSelect != null)
       {
            chkSelect.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkSelect_CheckedChanged);
            chkSelect.Visible = true;
       }
   }
```

The reason would be that `ItemDataBound` only fires on databinding.  So when you post back, your Repeater is reconstructed from ViewState, and `ItemCreated` is executed for every row, but `ItemDataBound` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Just invert the logic.

Create the `CheckBox` visible by default and with the `CheckedChanged` handler:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
    onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" 
    onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>    
                     <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSelect" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" />
                </td>
```

And on `ItemDataBound` event, set `Visible=false` for those you don't want to show:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (!((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row["DataType"].ToString().Trim().Equals("bool"))
    {
        CheckBox chkSelect = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chkSelect");
        chkSelect.Visible = false;
    }
}
```